# Bulk Update Query Eloquent without Foreach Loop - Laravel 5.1

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hi my database structure is as follows:

> Table: analytics

```
id | user_id(fk) | date | finalized(boolean)
```

Now I want to update the data in bulk. For example I want to select the data of user_id = 1 and date BETWEEN 2016-03-01 and 2016-03-20. And then I want to update the column finalized from 0 to 1 for all those records which I get in result.

What I had done is as follows:

```
 Analytics::where('user_id', $request->get('user_id'))
->whereBetween('date', [$request->get('from_date'), $request->get('to_date')])
->update(array('finalized' => 1));
```

But this is not working and not showing any error either. Please let know how can I do with the help of eloquent. Thanks in advance.

I have seen other questions in Stackover Flow too, but the answer suggests to run foreach loop, which I don't want. So is there any way, then kindly suggest me. Thanks again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eloquent model mass update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430716/eloquent-model-mass-update)

Comment: @crystalwill, I have seen that question too, but did not find what I actually wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that the `$fillable` property is set on the `Analytics` model, and it includes `finalized`? Also, have you confirmed that the request object has the dates and user ID you expect it to have?

Alternatively, you can go without Eloquent and hit the database directly.

```
DB::table('analytics')
    ->where('user_id', $request->user_id)->
    ->whereBetween('date', [$request->from_date, $request->to_date])
    ->update(['finalized' => 1]);
```

Comment: I'm checking into that. Thanks for suggesting