# How to loop input field value and insert to its row based on the database value in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, loops, laravel-5, eloquent

My problem is that I want to update the `quantity_served` based on quantity and insert the last loop value into the last record based on the input value.

[image: Current Database record]

For example, my input value has 180.

[image: Expected Result]

My code doesn't insert the last value of loop instead of the full value of quantity.

```php
$var = $request->get('id');
$data = bulkcorporatemodel::orderBy('id', 'asc');

foreach ($data as $item)
{
    if ($var == 0 || $var < 0)
    {
        break;
    }

    $bulkcorp = bulkcorporatemodel::find($item->id);
    $dummyHolder = $bulkcorp->quantity;
    $bulkcorp->quantity_served = $dummyHolder;
    $bulkcorp->save();

    $success_output = '<div class="alert alert-success">BULK DATA UPDATED</div>';
    $var = $var - $dummyHolder;
}
```

Comment: as far as I see you are trying to assign `$dummyHolder` to `$bulkcorp->quantityserved` which does not exists and it should be `$bulkcorp->quantity_served`. am I missing something ?

Comment: Apology sir typo error,
It still doesn't work sir.

Comment: Honestly I don't see anything wrong in your code except you are looping `$data as $data` which is wrong and try to change it to `$data as $item` and of course change `$data->id` to `$item->id` and see what happens

Comment: It doesn't work sir.

Comment: In `$data` try `$data = bulkcorporatemodel::all();` 
There is no need to order on id, it is always ordered on id. If in doubt, make use of the dumb and die function `dd($data);` and have a look if you get what you expect. Also (not needed but a kind of convention): make your ORM model names as `BulkCorporate` instead of `bulkcorporatemodel`. You're fine, but it will help readability when your code becomes bigger.

Comment: Thank you for the response sir, but the purpose of the asc order is to update data from the oldest up to the latest record sir.

Comment: Good. You can do this in 2 ways. `$data = bulkcorporatemodel::all()->sortBy('id', 'asc');` or `$data = bulkcorporatemodel::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();`

Comment: Still no luck sir

Comment: Oh, I see your mistake now. I'll give a full answer.

Comment: The value I inserted is 180 sir and then it updates the second row as the full quantity and it should be 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(**edit:** *I noticed that $item is in fact already in your $data collection, there is no need to find the item, it's already there. I have adapted the code accordingly and shorten the code all together :)* )

```
$var = $request->get('id');
$data = bulkcorporatemodel::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
foreach ($data as $bulkcorp)
{
    if ($var <= 0)
    {
        break;
    }

    $bulkcorp->update(
        ['quantity_served' => $bulkcorp->quantity]
    );

    $success_output = '<div class="alert alert-success">BULK DATA UPDATED</div>';
    $var = $var - $bulkcorp->quantity;
}
```

The keyword is `update()`

The thing not clear to me is what the relationship between `$var` and `$bulkcorp->quantity` is. If the var is indeed an id, you will get under 0 in one cycle and the rest of the $data collection won't be executed. If `$request->get('id')` is a high number, no problem.

But, this is what you really want to achieve. Normally, we should provide you this code, but ok, for once:

```
$stock = $request->get('id');
$data = bulkcorporatemodel::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
foreach ($data as $bulkcorp)
{
    if ($stock <= 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    $stock >= $bulkcorp->quantity ? $served = $bulkcorp->quantity : $served = $stock;

    $bulkcorp->update(
        ['quantity_served' => $served]
    );

    $success_output = '<div class="alert alert-success">BULK DATA UPDATED</div>';
    $stock = $stock - $bulkcorp->quantity;
}
```

Comment: still no luck sir, The 180 I entered returned to the first row 100 then the second row it return the full value again.

Comment: I was thinking about it too. I get it. $bulkcorp->quantity_served is the amount of stock that CAN be served, right? In other words, if stock runs out, just serve what you can and then the rest should be zero. Is it this you want to achieve?

Comment: The $bulkcorp->quantity is the value that can be only served/inserted to the $bulkcorp->quantity_served per row sir then, if the $var has an extra value  (The 80 value since 180-100 = 80), it will insert to the next row.

Comment: I have updated the code, please try it out. It should be fine now. Have a look at the second block of code.

Comment: The problem sir is that, It will not get the last value (80) instead the full value of $bulkcorp->quantity,

Comment: Try to make variables, functions, tables, fields and class names as humanly readable as possible. You can almost make English sentences out of them. That's the intuitive power of Laravel. And it will be much easier to debug, or ask others for help. Keep on going. It will all click together at some point. Just like what happens if you learn any other (spoken) language.

Comment: Noted sir.
The variables I used sir are just examples sir and for testing purposes sir, I have changed it to actual variable sir.