# How to update multiple rows in Laravel at once

Tags: php, laravel

I have a users' table and another table for their respective plans.I have a form that displays the users and their plans. I want a HR officer to be able to enter his/remarks to all plans and save all by a single submit button. Please help on how to refactor this code.

```
public function submitHrRemarks(Request $request){

    foreach ($plan_id = $request->plan_id as $key => $value) {

        if ($plan_id[$key] != '') {
      
            $hr_remarks = $request->hr_remarks[$key];
            
           // dd($hr_remarks,$value);

            $query = DB::table("weekly_plans")
                ->updateOrInsert(
                    [
                        'id' => $plan_id[$key], // pass your update id else empty
                    ],
                    //   $data =
                    [
                        'id' => $value,
                        'hr_remarks' => $hr_remarks,
                    ]);
        }
    }

    flash('You have successfully submitted the remarks!');
    return back();
}
```

[image: This image is the form showing users and their plans,also a HR officer can enter remarks]

Comment: What sort of help do you require? Whats wrong with this code

Comment: The problem is,it only picks the input from the last textarea and chucks into single letter and updates the rest with those letters. For example if the input in the last textarea was abcd ,then "a" will be inserted in the first row, "b" in the second row and "c" into the third row.

Comment: Can you show us a `print_r($request)`

Comment: print_r($request) seems like an infinite loop, the browser keeps loading forever without printing the output.

Comment: Then try a `dd($request)`

Answer (score 0):

You can check answer there

[Eloquent model mass update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430716/eloquent-model-mass-update)

Some time ago I researched this question and I came to the conclusion that cycle + query builder is the best option for mass update